# How can I find help learning Blender?

Tags: documentation

I was wondering if there would be anyone willing to tutor or teach me to start with blender, and get a decent way into it...I find the wiki and video tutorials somewhat difficult because I'm not very good at self-study. I understand it might not be worth it, as there is no way for me to pay you, but maybe we could work on projects together once we finished or as we go along? I'm also very willing to help you with your projects as I learn new concepts.

Thanks in advance, I appreciate it!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the correct site for this; here you can only ask particular questions about things that you are having trouble with. Try to ask this is blenderartists.org

Comment: I can be interested in giving advices and get some collaboration. Please write me an email at joshsanfelici@gmail.com, explaining what do you know of blender, modelling, animating, drawing skills and main interests in computer graphics and visual art in general.

Answer (score 2):

While not exactly the type of tutor you are asking about, the [Resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/) page, under the first category, *Learning*, there is a link to an answer which points to two on-line courses, one geared towards high school, and one geared towards college level learners. My suggestions is to work through either—or both— of these is as a start. You need not be a student of the sponsoring institutions to use the courses, and they are free. They are also complete courses as you might find in contemporary US high schools and colleges, where some classes are conducted on line. Having worked through these, you may find you don't have as much need for a tutor.